# Should I ask the same question across multiple games or one question to cover all the games?

Tags: discussion, questions

There is a couple of questions I want to post:

- When/where is the earliest I can catch a low level female Ralts?
- How many Unlocker Subchips do I need unlock all Purple Mystery Data?

Both of these questions I want to know the answer to multiple games which may end up having different answers. for the first one I want to ask in regards to most of the remake Pokemon Games and the later generations and I know the answer to this will be different depending on the game while the second one I want to ask for Megaman Battle Network 2-6 (as Unlocker Subchips aren't in Battle Network 1)

On the one hand I could just post these questions once but I'm concerned that there might be alot of incomplete answers before someone posts a complete answer themselves or combines all the incomplete ones. on the other hand i could post up a new question for each game but for the most part they would be the exact same except for which game they refer to.

So with these questions should I asked them as separate questions for each game or should I ask then once for each series

Comment: I would just ask two different questions, unless the question is about the same game.

Comment: You can ask about Ralts in one single question, it doesn't make sense to ask a question for each generation.